# Hiding the still objects when another createjs object passes through them in createjs

Tags: createjs

is there a way to hide the objects through which another object is passing in createjs. Also i have defined a path for the moving object but when it crosses other objects that come in the path; the objects are not hidden. It gives the view as if the moving object is cutting other objects. Is there a way in createjs through which i can handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there is a way for that. You can calculate the area of the intersection between 2 objects, and if it's a number higher than 0, then you can hide the second object. It will look something like this:

```
var bounds1 = object1.nominalBounds; //or .getBounds();
var bounds2 = object2.nominalBounds;
var rectangle = bounds1.intersection(bounds2);
if (rectangle != null && rectangle.width * rectangle.height > 0){
   object2.visible = false;
}
```

That's the gist of it, although depending on your objects and their containers, it might be a little more complicated than this, like needing to translate their coordinates to a global scope.